# tail-recursive list all sub-directories for the given file location

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I want to get all not empty directories for the given file location, for example:

```
/src/abc
/src/abc/123/123.txt
/src/abc/abc/123.txt
/src/abc/foo/123.txt
```

I want to get Seq[String]

```
/src/abc/123
/src/abc/abc
/src/abc/foo
```

I use this code.

```
def getAllDirectories(location: String): Seq[String] = {

    def recursiveListDirectories(f: File): Seq[File] = {
      val these = f.listFiles
      val directories = these.filter(_.isDirectory)
      directories ++ directories.flatMap(recursiveListDirectories)
    }
    recursiveListDirectories(new File(location)).filter(t => !t.listFiles().forall(_.isDirectory)).map(_.getPath)
  }
```

I wonder how can I make *recursiveListDirectories* method tail-recursive ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25250848/21755

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up your inner function to keep cumulative lists of both result directories, and directories that it still has to check. Try each directory to be checked in turn, adding any subdirectories to the waiting list of the next call. For example:

```
def getAllDirectories(location: String): Seq[String] = {

  def go(toCheck: List[File], results: List[File]): Seq[File] = toCheck match {
    case head :: tail =>
      val these = head.listFiles
      val directories = these.filter(_.isDirectory)
      val updated = if (these.size == directories.size) results else head :: results
      go(tail ++ directories, updated)
    case _ => results
  }

  go(new File(location) :: Nil, Nil).map(_.getPath)
}
```